# renumber residues in a protein structure file (pdb)

Tags: python, biopython

Hi
I am currently involved in making a website aimed at combining all papillomavirus information in a single place.
As part of the effort we are curating all known files on public servers (e.g. genbank)
One of the issues I ran into was that many (~50%) of all solved structures are not numbered according to the protein.
I.e. a subdomain was crystallized (amino acid 310-450) however the crystallographer deposited this as residue 1-140.
I was wondering whether anyone knows of a way to renumber the entire pdb file. I have found ways to renumber the sequence (identified by seqres), however this does not update the helix and sheet information.
I would appreciate it if you had any suggestions…
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I frequently encounter this problem too. After abandoning an old perl script I had for this I've been experimenting with some python instead. This solution assumes you've got Biopython, ProDy (http://www.csb.pitt.edu/ProDy/#prody) and EMBOSS (http://emboss.sourceforge.net/) installed.

I used one of the papillomavirus PDB entries here.

```
from Bio import AlignIO,SeqIO,ExPASy,SwissProt
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC
from Bio.Emboss.Applications import NeedleCommandline
from prody.proteins.pdbfile import parsePDB, writePDB
import os

oneletter = {
'ASP':'D','GLU':'E','ASN':'N','GLN':'Q',
'ARG':'R','LYS':'K','PRO':'P','GLY':'G',
'CYS':'C','THR':'T','SER':'S','MET':'M',
'TRP':'W','PHE':'F','TYR':'Y','HIS':'H',
'ALA':'A','VAL':'V','LEU':'L','ILE':'I',
}

# Retrieve pdb to extract sequence
# Can probably be done with Bio.PDB but being able to use the vmd-like selection algebra is nice
pdbname="2kpl"
selection="chain A"
structure=parsePDB(pdbname)
pdbseq_str=''.join([oneletter[i] for i in structure.select("protein and name CA and     %s"%selection).getResnames()])
alnPDBseq=SeqRecord(Seq(pdbseq_str,IUPAC.protein),id=pdbname)
SeqIO.write(alnPDBseq,"%s.fasta"%pdbname,"fasta")

# Retrieve reference sequence
accession="Q96QZ7"
handle = ExPASy.get_sprot_raw(accession)
swissseq = SwissProt.read(handle)
refseq=SeqRecord(Seq(swissseq.sequence,IUPAC.protein),id=accession)
SeqIO.write(refseq, "%s.fasta"%accession,"fasta")

# Do global alignment with needle from EMBOSS, stores entire sequences which makes numbering easier
needle_cli = NeedleCommandline(asequence="%s.fasta"%pdbname,bsequence="%s.fasta"%accession,gapopen=10,gapextend=0.5,outfile="needle.out")
needle_cli()
aln = AlignIO.read("needle.out", "emboss")
os.remove("needle.out")
os.remove("%s.fasta"%pdbname)
os.remove("%s.fasta"%accession)

alnPDBseq = aln[0]
alnREFseq = aln[1]
# Initialize per-letter annotation for pdb sequence record
alnPDBseq.letter_annotations["resnum"]=[None]*len(alnPDBseq)
# Initialize annotation for reference sequence, assume first residue is #1
alnREFseq.letter_annotations["resnum"]=range(1,len(alnREFseq)+1)

# Set new residue numbers in alnPDBseq based on alignment
reslist = [[i,alnREFseq.letter_annotations["resnum"][i]] for i in range(len(alnREFseq)) if alnPDBseq[i] != '-']
for [i,r] in reslist:
    alnPDBseq.letter_annotations["resnum"][i]=r

# Set new residue numbers in the structure
newresnums=[i for i in alnPDBseq.letter_annotations["resnum"][:] if i != None]
resindices=structure.select("protein and name CA and %s"%selection).getResindices()
resmatrix = [[newresnums[i],resindices[i]] for i in range(len(newresnums)) ]
for [newresnum,resindex] in resmatrix:  
    structure.select("resindex %d"%resindex).setResnums(newresnum)

writePDB("%s.renumbered.pdb"%pdbname,structure)
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm the maintainer of [pdb-tools](http://www.pdb-tools.googlecode.com/) - which may be a tool that can assist you.

I have recently modified the [`residue-renumber`](http://code.google.com/p/pdb-tools/source/browse/trunk/pdbTools/pdb_residue-renumber.py) script within my application to provide more flexibility. It can now `renumber` *hetatms* and *specific chains*, and either force the residue numbers to be continuous or just add a user-specified offset to all residues.

Please let me know if this assists you.

Answer (score 0):

1. [pdb-tools](http://code.google.com/p/pdb-tools/)
2. [Phenix](http://www.phenix-online.org/documentation/pdbtools.htm) pdb-tools
3. BioPython or Bio3D

Check the first one - it should fit your needs

Comment: The pdb-tools 'renumberer' is not to recommend. It for example doesn't even consider HETATM entries.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. See my posting here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786803/protein-sequence-alignment-from-protein-databank-to-cosmic-or-uniprot
Have you ever solved it?

Comment: no luck this far...none of the suggested tools accomplish what I need